# can i save context in a variable?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

how can I save the main activity context in a variable to use it in a function of another class? is there a specific method i can use?

I have a class that contains the functions that I would like to use in my main_activity, one of the functions, within the routePath function, which I report below (line 2), requires that the context be passed as a parameter to draw the path on the map, that I would like to know is how can I pass the context when the function is called in the main_activity.
I thought it was possible to save the main activity context in a variable and then retrieve it in the second class.
I can share the whole code if needed.

```
fun routePath(p1Latit: Double, p1Laong: Double, p2Latit: Double, p2Laong: Double){
        println("inizio")
        val roadManager: RoadManager = OSRMRoadManager(context, "lolloMaps")
        OSRMRoadManager.MEAN_BY_FOOT
        println("passo1 - creoArrayList")
        val waypoints = arrayListOf<GeoPoint>()
        println("passo2 - CreoPuntiEAggiungoInArrayList")
        val startPoint: GeoPoint = GeoPoint(p1Latit, p1Laong) //43.12628, 12.04705
        waypoints.add(startPoint)
        val endPoint: GeoPoint = GeoPoint(p2Latit, p2Laong) //43.12124, 11.97211
        waypoints.add(endPoint)
        println("passo3 - CreoStrada")
        road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints)
        if (road.mStatus != Road.STATUS_OK){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Errore nel caricamento di road - status = " + road.mStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        println("passo4 - CreoPolilinea")
        val roadOverlay: Polyline = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road)
        println("passo5 - AggiungoPolilineaAllaMappa")
        mapView.overlays.add(roadOverlay)
        mapView.invalidate()
```

I think i should correct the last two lines as well as mapView has been declared in main_Activity, is that right?

Comment: Every activity has its own context, and a fragment can use its activity context using requireContext().
If you are trying to use context in some other class, then do share your code.

Comment: You shouldn't store references to Activities in things that aren't running *within* that Activity - it can cause memory leaks when the Activity has been destroyed, but something else is holding it in memory. Generally you should use `applicationContext` where possible, and pass it into functions as a parameter (you see this a lot in Android, where methods require a `Context`). Injecting dependencies like this, instead of putting them somewhere globally accessible, is usually considered a good idea - you'll have to show some code if there's a specific example you're thinking of though!

Comment: if you need the Context out of fragment or activity, you can use Hilt and pass the constructor like this `class Test @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context)`
and by the way you can pass your context as constructor of some classes

Comment: I updated the question for clarity, thx everyone!

Comment: when I try to use the applicationContext function the app crashes without reporting errors, I tried with the solution suggested below by Taha and everything seems to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by passing to the class that contains the function both the context and the mapView as constructor parameters

Answer (score -1):

You can use

> ```
> Context context = MainActivity.this;
> ```

then pass that `context` to the method you require.

like this `recyclerViewAdapter` here (no need to say you could pass that `MainActivity.this` directly instead of putting it inside the `context` variable):

> ```
> adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(context, toDoList);
> ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).